# How can I add shiny surface to UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, light

[image]

How can I add shiny surface to UITableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done easily.  From the screenshot you supplied it appears that most of what you're pointing out is photoshopped images positioned with UI elements supplied from within Xcode and customized via code.

The tableView for example appears to be on a Grouped Table View laying on top of a photoshopped textured image.  The tableView itself has a custom color to all the cells and a custom color and shadow to the cell separators.  You can use Google to see how to customize a UITableView pretty easily.

But like said, most of this is from the magic of Photoshop.

Comment: I think it is a plain tableview. Actually screenshot is from iPad Reminders.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own views and photoshop them.